# Spring Boot App works on H2, but fails on AWS RDS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

I have created a simple Project Management App with H2 database and it works fine.  However, when I try to change the datasource to mysql on AWS, I'm getting errors :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'ip.com' (using password: YES)
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iEmpRepo' defined in com.pma.scratch.demo.repos.iEmpRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Now I know for sure my connection credentials are correct, because I connected using DataGrip just fine, and I even created a new spring boot app in intellij and I was able to connect to the same database and create tables using jpa.

Here is the application properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql.....:3306/database_name
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=*****
```

No idea why I'm getting an access denied error, and the BeanCreation error confuses me because my app creates beans just fine using H2.

Comment: your spring.datasource.url does not appear to be pointing to your AWS database ? Or is it. Hard to tell.

Comment: It is pointing to it.  I just hid the entire database connection string.

Comment: Really no idea how this happened, but after stepping away and rubber ducking with a colleague, the issue magically vanished and I was able to connect.   I did have to update the mysql drivers to the latest to get the table schemas to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the driver is missing. Add this:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

or

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And don't forget the jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

If error continues, get more log with this property

```
debug=true
```

Comment: good call.  the driver was not updated for my-sql-connector.  I used spring-boot-starters to add the dependency to the pom.xml, but it still wasn't updated.  Anyways now it works!